# Is there a lower-bound version of the triangle inequality for more than two terms?

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces, absolute-value, estimation

The triangle inequality $|x+y|\leq|x|+|y|$ can be generalized by induction to $$|x_1+\ldots+ x_n|\leq|x_1|+\ldots+|x_n|.$$

Can we generalize the version $|x+y|\geq||x|-|y||$ to $n$ terms too? I need to estimate an expression of the form $|x+y+z|$ from below so that the estimate depends on the absolute values of $x,y,z$, and I think the triangle inequality should be enough, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Note that 
$$
|x+y|\ge{\large{|}}|x|-|y|{\large{|}}
$$
is a combination of
$$
|x|\le|y|+|x+y|\qquad\text{and}\qquad|y|\le|x|+|x+y|
$$
This same idea can be applied to the standard multi-term triangle inequality
$$
\left|\,\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\,\right|\le\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|
$$
To make an estimate from below of a sum, usually we have a large term and several smaller terms to get something like
$$
\left|\,\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\,\right|\ge\max_j\left(|x_j|-\sum_{i\ne j}|x_i|\right)
$$
Depending on the data and what you know about it, similar inequalities can be derived.

Comment: Does the claim $|x+y| \geq ||x| - |y||$ have a widely accepted name?

Comment: [Reverse Triangle Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality) (Note that $|{-y}|=|y|$)

Comment: Silly me, I hadn't realised it's the same. Thanks!